# Spring injects a one-element Set instead of an empty Set

Tags: java, spring

We have an application where we are trying to inject an empty `java.util.HashSet` into a member of type `java.util.Set`, in a class which itself is a `@Component`. Spring seems to inject a `HashSet` with one element of the containing type. Any idea why Spring doesn't just inject an empty set?

**Set element class:**

```
@Component
public class SetElement
{
    private String value;

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Class that contains a Set as a member:**

```
@Component
public class MyClassWithSet
{
    @Autowired
    private Set<SetElement> setOfElements;

    protected void setStringSet(Set<SetElement> stringSet)
    {
        this.setOfElements = stringSet;
    }

    public Set<SetElement> getStringSet()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(setOfElements);
    }
}
```

**Spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <bean id="setOfElements" class="java.util.HashSet" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vikdor.db " />
</beans>
```

**Sample test case to confirm the behavior**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations =
{ "classpath:META-INF/spring.xml" })
public class SpringSetTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MyClassWithSet myClassWithSet;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        assertNotNull(myClassWithSet);
        assertNotNull(myClassWithSet.getStringSet());
        assertTrue(myClassWithSet.getStringSet().isEmpty());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that the *only* test method in the test class?

Comment: Yes, nothing else. In fact, these are the four files in the entire eclipse project where I tried to reproduce this problem (after we discovered this in a large application).

Comment: out of curiousity what is the element that the set contains?

Comment: The set contains elements of type `SetElement` described in the first class, in the question.

Comment: I would recommend turning Spring's debug logging on, and watching for references to the bean. I have to believe that there's something in your classpath that Spring is finding that overrides what you think you're testing. I also have to wonder why you have `@Component` on what appears to be a DTO.

Comment: @Vikdor - *matt b* was asking aboutthe actual object contained in the set instance -- the thing that makes it not-empty

Comment: `I also have to wonder why you have @Component on what appears to be a DTO.` I agree with this but that is more of a fundamental modeling question.

Comment: @parsifal, sorry, I still didn't understand what mattb was asking. could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: add `System.err.println(myClassWithSet.getStringSet().iterator().next())`

Comment: @parsifal, Got it, it is adding an element of type `SetElement` itself with value of `value` attribute as `null`.

Comment: I think the debug log is your best bet. Because you've marked `SetElement` with `@Component`, Spring will create a bean from it (with the value of null), but there should be nothing to cause Spring to autowire that bean into the set.

Comment: Ignore my last sentence; *nd* has the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `@Autowired` on a typed collection instance, then all beans in the application context that satisfy the type are injected:

> It is also possible to provide all beans of a particular type from the
>   ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that
>   expects an array of that type [...] The same applies for typed
>   collections:

```
public class MovieRecommender {

  private Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs;

  @Autowired
  public void setMovieCatalogs(Set<MovieCatalog> movieCatalogs) {
      this.movieCatalogs = movieCatalogs;
  }

  // ...
}
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation

Thus, your single instance of `SetElement` is injected into the `@Autowired Set<SetElement>`. A possible solution would be to use a setter for the field. Alternatively, you could use the `@Qualifier` annotation or the `@Resource` annotation to refer to the bean by name.